# smarty replace multiple values

Tags: replace, smarty, prestashop

I have ..tpl file with this line:

```
{$error|replace:"pno":"personal number error"}
```

I need to modify it so multiple values will be replaced, sort of:

```
{$error|replace:"pno_error":"personal number error", "error_1":"1", "error_2":"2"}
```

I need to make sure the code is correctly formed. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like so

```
{assign "find" array('pno', 'error_1', 'error_2')}
{assign "repl" array('personal number error', 1, 2)}
{assign "text" 'error_1 and pno and error_2 are friends'}
{$text|replace:$find:$repl}
```

btw: dont'cha rather do it through a controller and in tpl files use final values?

**EDIT**

> how to make it to replace the exact match only, for example if the $text is 'pno', then replace it, but if the $text is 'pnopno', then do nothing?

In that case, you can use regular expressions, however, it is not possible in an array (as far as I know) and you need to do it step by step, or rather a command after command.

Regarding of replacing `pno` and not `pnopno`, you need to figure out your own regular expression to suit your needs.

```
{assign "text" 'error_1 and pno and error_2 are friends'}
{$text|regex_replace:"/(\s)(pno)(\s)/":"personal number error"|regex_replace:"/(error_1)/":"1"|regex_replace:"/(error_2)/":"2"}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! Now another question: how to make it to replace the exact match only, for example if the $text is 'pno', then replace it, but if the $text is 'pnopno', then do nothing?

Comment: It is sort of posible, just in a slightly different way, check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the short code:

```
{$text = "error_1 and pno and error_2 are friends"}
{$find = ['pno', 'error_1', 'error_2']}
{$repl = ['personal number error', 1, 2]}

{$text|replace:$find:$repl}
```