# smarty processes strong (text) format over php -> put out modified php only

Tags: php, formatting, smarty, smarty3

Have prepared a string modification with php in the classes file. Now in the smarty template (tpl) file when outputting the string I get a wrong text format. The project uses smarty 3.1-DEV and php 5.6.

I have this php code and assigned the variable in php class file:

```
    $pattern = '/' . implode('|', $allergens_searchnames) . '/iu';
    echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) { 
    return mb_strtoupper($m[0]); }, $prodIngredients);
    }
    $this->assign("articleIngredients", $prodIngredients);
```

Outputting directly with "echo" over classes file I get on front end the desired format:
"Zutaten: 
MARILLEn (75%), Zucker, Zitronensaft, Geliermittel: PEKTINe (aus Apfel)"

Implementation over smarty output is wrong:
"Zutaten:
Marillen (75%), Zucker, Zitronensaft, Geliermittel: Pektine (aus Apfel)"

Here like I implemented to the tpl-file:

```
<span class="pull-right">
{if isset($articleIngredients)}
<p>{$articleIngredients|unescape:'html'}</p>
{/if}   
</span>
```

Due to the fact that I don't know much of the project and of smarty it is nearly impossible to fix this for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to implement it directly on the template: [smarty replace multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385120/smarty-replace-multiple-values)

problem is to hardcode all diffrent possibilities to replace into two arrays. Maybe I can find another solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of these 2 might help you. Try using unescape:'htmlall' or Try printing the text as literal text

```
<span class="pull-right">
{if isset($articleIngredients)}
<p>{$articleIngredients}|unescape:'htmlall'}</p>
{/if}
```

source: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl

Anything within {literal}{/literal} tags is not interpreted, but displayed as-is.

```
<span class="pull-right">
{if isset($articleIngredients)}
<p>{literal}{$articleIngredients}{/literal}</p>
{/if}   
</span>
```

Source: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl

Comment: what is the  error it gives? I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: The first attempt with unescape:'htmlall' puts only the string with capitalized first letter out. Need the exact string manipulation though with specific words capitalized.

Comment: had syntax error. Tried again and found that it literally puts out the raw code to my content like: "{$articleIngredients}|unescape:'htmlall'}". I need the content to be output inside of the variable with exact modifications I made before in php.

Comment: Are you loading this section directly from PHP or from AJAX? if you are loading from AJAX then you can set the parent div for the result as literal then append the result you are getting from server to that div.

Comment: use only from php